# postDelayed inside while loop doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, loops, while-loop, handler

I want to delay the app before updating the messages to make it look realistic.
when I am trying to delay updating one message it works just fine as shown below

```
if (currentMessage.getMessageStatue() == MESSAGE_RECEIVED) {
                    handler = new Handler();
                    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            updateMessage();
                            notifyAdapter();
                            currentMessage++;
                        }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
                }
```

But the problem is that when I am trying to loop throw each message and perform the same task, the app keeps delaying and android force it to stop. this is what I am trying to do:

```
while (currentMessage.getMessageStatue() == MESSAGE_RECEIVED) {
                    handler = new Handler();
                    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            updateMessage();
                            notifyAdapter();
                            currentMessage++;
                        }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
                }
```

can I overcome this issue and use a postDelayed handler inside a while loop?

Comment: I wonder where you put your `while` loop in?

Comment: inside setOnClickListener which is inside the main onCreate method

Comment: postDelay() should be fine, check your while looping that may causing rapid creating postDelay multiple times which is not good design. try different approach rather than while loop.

Comment: I checked my while loop without the delaying task and it worked fine, but the problem occurred when I am implementing the delaying task

Comment: If currentMessage is not changing your apps goes into an infinite loop. Can you post all your code?

Comment: You are either getting ANR or OOM, whichever come first. Do not put `while` loop in main thread.